# Conky on multiple display?

Tags: xorg, conky

I have an external display that show the right part of my screen (`--right-of` option in xrandr),

And my conky panel was just gone. (occupies space, but not visible on both display)

What I want is the same view of conky, for both my laptop display and the external one, any thoughts?

Thanks

**Part of my conkyrc, might be helpful**

```
own_window yes 
if_up_strictness address
own_window_colour 262729
own_window_transparent no 
own_window_type panel
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
use_spacer right 
use_xft yes
font snap.se-7
xftalpha 1
text_buffer_size 2048 
#alignment tl
alignment bl
gap_x 0
gap_y 3
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of solutions to do it. The gap_x and gap_y is the worst one. The configuration of the display is much more complex. I also have an external monitor on a laptop.

My conky config files are in the startup list and they look like this. I use Ubuntu 12.04:

```
bash -c "sleep 30; conky -c conky1 -a top_right -x 7 -y 70 -d"

bash -c "sleep 30; conky -c conky2 -a top_left -x 150 -y 550 -d"
```

gap_x and gap_y in both files are set to 1. Using relative coordinates will always output in the same place.

From terminal: conky -c conky1 -a top_right -x 7 -y 70 -d

I do not have to reset the value of gap-x or y every time I boot with a secondary display.

[image: single monitor conky]
[image: dual monitor conky]

Comment: beautiful! it worked great in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: For me `top_right` always put conky on the top right of my left monitor (both monitor are set as one display `:0`), so I had to use a negative value for `-x`, the width of the right monitor: `conky -c my.conkyrc -a top_right -x -1440`

Answer (score 7):

The un-documented setting `xinerama_head` was added to simplify things since `-x`/`-y` approach is time-consuming and hard to maintain (or lack of flexibility) if different positions/resolutions/monitors are used.

```
conky.config = {
  xinerama_head = 1 (or 2, 3...)
}
```

For [further reading](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/249).

Answer (score 3):

Get the mouse position coordinates with xdotool

```
xdotool getmouselocation --shell
```

Just immediately get the coordinates, maybe you need time to move to a specified location

```
sleep 3 ;xdotool getmouselocation --shell
```

Use your mouse to move the stone side of the coordinates you want to show where conky

> X=**1920** Y=266 SCREEN=0 WINDOW=27263065

So this execution, the first to eat conkyrc settings (including coordinates ), and the second will be displayed on the right side at coordinates 1920

```
conky
conky -x 1920
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, this will also place the element on the right on various monitors. Even if you find the value for the gap_x variable to work on your 17" monitor, it will not work on another one with a different rezolution, say of 21".